# Issue with vue-light-gallery in Nuxt 3: "Failed to resolve component: LightGallery

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt3

I'm encountering an issue with vue-light-gallery in Nuxt 3. I've set up a file in the 'plugins' directory with the following code:

```js
import VueLightGallery from 'vue-light-gallery';
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return VueLightGallery;
});
```

I've also configured the NuxtConfig with the necessary modules and plugins:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: true },
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/google-fonts'],
    googleFonts: {
        display: 'swap',
        families: {
            Rubik: true,
            Raleway: {
                wght: [100, 300, 400, 600],
                ital: [100]
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        '~/plugins/lightGallery.client.js',
    ],
    app: {
        pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' }
    }
})
```

File where I use LightGallery

````
const index = null;
const datas = [
  { title: "img 1", url: "https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=1" },
  { title: "img 2", url: "https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=2" }
];
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="data, dataIndex in datas" :key="dataIndex" @click="index = dataIndex">
      <img class="test" width="180px" height="180px" :src="data.url"/>
    </div>  
    <LightGallery :images="datas" :index="index" :disable-scroll="false" @close="index = null"/>
  </section>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.test {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>```


However, when I use LightGallery in another file, I receive the following error:

```[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: LightGallery
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
[Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous> is missing template or render function.
````

Comment: So, you're attempting to register a component so that it could be used globally, which is fine but takes some config to do so, however, I ask, do you need to do this? How often are you rendering a light gallery to warrant this? Presumably you'd keep the light house in just one file. So, could you not just import it directly where you're going to use it, rather than trying to make it available globally? One file with: `import VueLightGallery from 'vue-light-gallery'` and `<LightGallery ...`

Comment: I need global gallery beacue I use her in few components

Comment: Personally I would manually `import` it everywhere; this helps with optimization later (e.g. tree-shaking, etc).

Comment: Maybe you're right that;s will be better solution. But If i import to component i have error 500 document is not define

Comment: Maybe you have to restart the server (ie `npm run dev`).

Comment: Have you tried doing it the [documented way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-light-gallery#usage-with-nuxt)

Answer (score 0):

Checked `vue-light-gallery` github page. There was no updates for 4 years. Vue 2 is in `package.json` dev dependencies. Don't think you can make it work in Nuxt3.
As it is no longer maintained - I would suggest you to just copy source code ([source](https://github.com/peremp/vue-light-gallery/blob/master/src/light-gallery.vue)) and migrate Vue2 code to Vue3 in case there is anything to migrate ([migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/)).
If you will get it into `/components` folder - it will be automatically registered by Nuxt for you to use